# Connection between Schur multipliers in representation theory and functional analysis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I was wondering if there is any connection between two things called Schur multipliers or is it just a coincidence? Namely, in representation/group theory the Schur multiplier of a group $G$ is its second homology group $H_2(G, \mathbb{Z})$. In functional analysis a function $\varphi \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Schur multiplier if for any bounded linear operator $A: l^2 \to l^2$ with matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$ (with respect to the standard orthonormal basis of $l^2$) the matrix $(\varphi(i,j)a_{i,j})_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$ defines a bounded linear operator.

Comment: a coincidence, IMHO. I.Schur did fundamental work in group theory as well as in analysis, etc...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Issai_Schur

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227995/is-there-a-link-between-h-2g-mathbbz-the-schur-multiplier-of-a-group-an (however I don't vote, because I have some stupid "privilege" in gr.group-theory which would make the question closed as duplicate based on my only vote).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you very much. Yes, I think this is basically the same question and I somehow missed it. This one may be closed then. Sorry. :(