# Is the Klein group related to the Klein bottle?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, cv.complex-variables

Is the group of symmetries of the rectangle-not-square related to the Klein bottle mathematically?

The reason I am asking is because I want to put a Klein bottle coffee cup in a joke about V_4 and wonder if this would be a good idea.

Comment: Is it an obvious yes? Am I missing something? Or is it an obvious no it's just the guy?

Comment: Ok sorry I got the answer from Twitter that these are two different people. Still...

Comment: Asking whether two mathematical objects "are connected" is not a mathematical question.

Comment: Daniel, I admit I could have solved my question with a Google search, but it is not unmathematical to ask if two mathematical objects are connected. A lot of math is about connecting mathematics.

Comment: I don't this is a particularly great question, since it is relatively easy to answer with some online searching and "asking Twitter", but I admit there is precedent: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227995/is-there-a-link-between-h-2g-mathbbz-the-schur-multiplier-of-a-group-an

Comment: My point is that mathematics is a discipline where everything is connected in one way or another to everything else. You could have meant virtually anything to someone reading your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to wikipedia ([bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle), [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)) they're both named after Felix Klein, but appeared in different papers on completely different topics. The bottle comes from his [notes](https://www.kleinbottle.com/The%20First%20Klein%20Bottle.html) from 1882 and the group in [Lectures on the icosahedron and the solution of equations of the fifth degree](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059413439/mode/2up).

Klein group is also a bit of a pun, since Klein means small in German.

Comment: Since they are in different papers does that mean they are not connected?

Comment: You can see from the topics of the linked papers. One is about Galois theory, the other about topology.

Comment: Ah nice and I heard it was Vierergruppe for 4. But still this only gives evidence that they might be connected.

Comment: Oh yes one must never mix topology and algebra.

Comment: I mean I linked the sources you can see for yourself whether either of these has such a mix...

Comment: Thanks Noah I appreciate the answer